# (PHP) How to get the value from dropdown list and use the variable as as part of the html link

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, dropdown

First created the dropdown list

However, I'm not sure how to turn the selected choice (variable) as part of the input of the html

```
<p style="text-align:center"> CORONAVIRUS (COVID-19) Checker</p> 
<br>    
<label for="Country" >Choose a country: </label>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
  <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<button onclick="searchcovid()">Submit </button>


<p style="text-align:center">Covid Modules Map</p>

<div id=covidbing class="bingwidget" data-type="covid19_modules" data-modules='[{"_type": "map", "location-id":"/japan"}]'></div>

<script src="//www.bing.com/widget/bootstrap.answer.js" async="">

</script>
```

Comment: What does your `searchcovid()` function do?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JavaScript normally runs on the client, unless you are using Node.js, but then you wouldn't be using PHP.  Using pure JavaScript to manipulate the DOM document.getElementById("country"), returns the element for the select node.  Check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: the searchid() get the result from an API  (managed how to work)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use HTML forms to send user inputs to the server, or you can go for `ajax` if you want to asynchronously interact with the server.

**HTML Forms** are generally used when you simply want to send some data to the server and perform some action on it, eg.  *a login system*.
Use this if you are just beginning to learn HTML and PHP.

Here's a simple example of a `<form>`.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form action="where-you-want-to-send-data.php" method="GET">
  <p style="text-align:center"> CORONAVIRUS (COVID-19) Checker</p>
  <label for="Country" >Choose a country: </label>
  <select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   </select><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The `action` attribute points to the page where you want to send the data. The method attribute generally has two values `GET/POST` and is used to specify what kind of request it is.
You can learn more about get/post here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

If `HTML forms` is not what you are looking for, `ajax` might be your way!

Comment: actually, would like to change the location in the following path : Japan becomes the variable: 

<p style="text-align:center">Covid Modules Map</p>
<div id=covidbing class="bingwidget" data-type="covid19_modules" data-modules='[{"_type": "map", "location-id":"/japan"}]'></div>
<script src="//www.bing.com/widget/bootstrap.answer.js" async="">

</script> >

Comment: So you want to change the data-modules attribute of the div "covidbing"? You can change it using some javascript. But even though if you change the attribute, there must be a function that is fired to get the results from the API. Is that what the "searchcovid" function does?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you write your select attributes right. This could help you fixing your issue

using the GET-**method** while specifying your handler script (e.g. **file-to-handle-get-request-inc.php**) in the **action**-attribute on a new **form**-tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="GET" action="file-to-handle-get-request-inc.php">
  <p style="text-align:center"> CORONAVIRUS (COVID-19) Checker</p>
  <label for="country">Choose a country: </label>
  <select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   </select>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <p style="text-align:center">Covid Modules Map</p>
<div id="covidbing" class="bingwidget" data-type="covid19_modules" data-modules='[{"_type": "map", "location-id":"/japan"}]'></div>
<script src="https://www.bing.com/widget/bootstrap.answer.js" async=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your handler script could be something like:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET"){     if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && !empty($_GET['country'])){$selectedCountry =  htmlspecialchars($_GET['country']);     var_dump($selectedCountry) ;     } }
```